# Using REST in TCL to POST in JSON format?

Tags: json, rest, curl, tcl

Essentially what I'm attempting to do is post to a REST API, but no matter what I do I end up with HTTP 400.  Here is my extremely quick and extremely dirty code:

```
package require rest
package require json

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket
set credentials {username admin password LabPass1}
set url1 [format "%s/%s" "https://127.0.0.1:8834" session]
set unformattedToken [dict get [::json::json2dict [::rest::post $url1 $credentials]] token]
set cookie [format "token=%s" $unformattedToken]    
set header [list X-Cookie $cookie Content-type application/json] 
set config [list method post format json headers $header] 

set url [format "%s/%s" "https://127.0.0.1:8834" scans]
set uuid 7485-2345-566
set name "Testing TCL Network Scan"
set desc "Basic Network Scan using API"
set pid 872
set target 127.0.0.1

set data {{"uuid":"$uuid","settings": {"name":"$name","description":"$desc", "policy_id":"$pid","text_targets":"$target", "launch":"ONETIME","enabled":false,"launch_now":true}}}
set jsonData [json::json2dict $data]
set response [::rest::simple $url $jsonData $config]
```

I've tried using the above code and I've also tried removing the json::json2dict call and just sending the data.  I believe, and I could be wrong, that my issue is the data is going as line-based text data:

```
POST /scans HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8834
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.0) http/2.8.9 Tcl/8.6.4
Connection: close
X-Cookie: token=301b8dcdf855a29b5b902cf8d93c49750935c925a965445e
Content-type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,compress
Content-Length: 270

uuid=7485-2345-566&settings=name%20%7BTesting%20TCL%20Network%20Scan%7D%20description%20%7BBasic%20Network%20Scan%20using%20API%7D%20policy_id%20872%20text_targets%20127.0.0.1%20launch%20ONETIME%20enabled%20false%20launch_now%20true
```

I've reviewed the JSON documentation, and the REST documentation but I'm having a hard time finding an example of posting using JSON format.  Here is what this looks like in a curl command:

```
curl https://127.0.0.1:8834/scans -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Cookie: token= <token>' -d '{"uuid":"7485-2345-566","settings":{"name":"Testing TCL Network Scan","description":"Basic Network Scan using API", "policy_id":"872","text_targets":"127.0.0.1", "launch":"ONETIME","enabled":false,"launch_now":true}'
```

Comment: Did my suggestion help? Are there more problems that need to be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is that the values in the query aren't evaluated. `"uuid":"$uuid"` becomes `"uuid":"$uuid"`, for instance. This is because of the braces around the value that `data` is set to.

The best solution would seem to be to not create a json object and then convert it to a `dict`, but instead create the `dict` directly, like this:

```
set data [list uuid $uuid settings [list name $name description $desc policy_id $pid text_targets $target launch ONETIME enabled false launch_now true]]
```

or like this, for shorter lines:

```
dict set data uuid $uuid
dict set data settings name $name
dict set data settings description $desc
dict set data settings policy_id $pid
dict set data settings text_targets $target
dict set data settings launch ONETIME
dict set data settings enabled false
dict set data settings launch_now true
```

or by some other method.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I had success with:

set response [::rest::simple $url "" $config $jsonData]

documentation is:
::rest::simple url query ?config? ?body?

"" is for Query parameter, I don't need it so it's empty

JsonData in my case was a json string, I will try to use a dictionary to see if it works.